# Perform some operation if 2 pandas dataframe have same entries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

I have 2 dataframes (**purchase** and **sales**) as follows:

**PURCHASE:**

| Name | item | voucher | Amt | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Item1 | Purchase | 10000 | 100 |
| B | Item2 | Purchase | 500 | 50 |
| B | Item1 | Purchase | 2000 | 20 |
| C | Item3 | Purchase | 1000 | 100 |
| D | Item4 | Purchase | 500 | 100 |
| A | Item3 | Purchase | 5000 | 50 |

**SALES:**

| Name | item | voucher | Amt | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Item1 | Sales | 5300 | 50 |
| B | Item2 | Sales | 450 | 40 |
| B | Item1 | Sales | 1675 | 15 |
| C | Item3 | Sales | 1800 | 100 |

I want an output dataframe where if the person (`Name`) sells an item, the `Amt` and `Qty` should be deducted from the **purchase** dataframe and a new dataframe should be created with the remaining `Amt` and `Qty` as shown below:

**OUTPUT DATAFRAME:**

| Name | item | voucher | Amt | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Item1 | Remaining | 4700 | 50 |
| A | Item3 | Remaining | 5000 | 50 |
| B | Item2 | Remaining | 50 | 10 |
| B | Item1 | Remaining | 325 | 5 |
| C | Item3 | Remaining | -800 | 0 |
| D | Item4 | Remaining | 500 | 100 |

Notice that whatever items have been sold by a person (`Name`) has been deducted from the **purchase** dataframe and the remaining items (`Amt` and `Qty`) are stored in a new output dataframe. Also person `D` never sold any items even then it should be included in the output dataframe.

Thanks in advance!

**Dataframe**

```py
import pandas as pd

Purchases = {
    "Name": ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A"],
    "item": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item1", "Item3", "Item4", "Item3"],
    "voucher": ["Purchase", "Purchase", "Purchase", "Purchase", "Purchase", "Purchase"],
    "Amt": [10000, 500, 2000, 1000, 500, 5000],
    "Qty": [100, 50, 20, 100, 100, 50],
}

Purchases = pd.DataFrame(Purchases)

Sales = {
    "Name": ["A", "B", "B", "C"],
    "item": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item1", "Item3"],
    "voucher": ["Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales"],
    "Amt": [5300, 450, 1675, 1800],
    "Qty": [50, 40, 15, 100],
}

Sales = pd.DataFrame(Sales)
```

Comment: I think there is mistake in your input dataframe: (C, item3) should be 800 and not 1800.

Comment: @Corralien I don't see where, it seems it's 1800

Comment: In SALES dataframe. The result is 200 so the subtraction should be 1000 - 800 and not 1000 - 1800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using good old index alignment:

```
tmp = Purchases.set_index(['Name', 'item'])
out = (tmp
       .sub(Sales.set_index(['Name', 'item'])[['Amt', 'Qty']])
       .combine_first(tmp).assign(voucher='Remaining')
       .reset_index()[Purchases.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
  Name   item    voucher     Amt    Qty
0    A  Item1  Remaining  4700.0   50.0
1    A  Item3  Remaining  5000.0   50.0
2    B  Item1  Remaining   325.0    5.0
3    B  Item2  Remaining    50.0   10.0
4    C  Item3  Remaining  -800.0    0.0
5    D  Item4  Remaining   500.0  100.0
```

Comment: I don't know if I love U or hate U lol ;-p

Comment: @LaurentB. then rather love me please, there's enough hate in this world :p

Comment: okay, that's what my dice indicates me :-p

Answer (score 2):

```py
Purchases = Purchases.set_index(['Name', 'item'])
Sales = Sales.set_index(['Name', 'item'])
Purchases['Amt'].update(Purchases['Amt'].sub(Sales['Amt']))
Purchases['Qty'].update(Purchases['Qty'].sub(Sales['Qty']))
Purchases = Purchases.reset_index().sort_values(by=['Name'])

print(Purchases)
```

```py
  Name   item   voucher   Amt  Qty
0    A  Item1  Purchase  4700   50
5    A  Item3  Purchase  5000   50
1    B  Item2  Purchase    50   10
2    B  Item1  Purchase   325    5
3    C  Item3  Purchase  -800    0
4    D  Item4  Purchase   500  100
```

Comment: Thanks for this info Corralien, `ìnplace` will be deprecated in next Pandas version (ie Pandas 2). So one has to take the good habits now ;-)

Comment: Probably `update` will be deprecated too. (I hope :-)). I think all methods should always return a copy (Explicit is better than implicit). Only `.loc`, `.iloc` and other item assignment should modify the DataFrame/Series in place because they are explicit. IMHO :-)

Comment: Yes sure it would be preferable but `update` is not deprecated in Pandas 2 : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html (version 2.0.0 (stable) ). But I must admit even if `update` is very useful,I don't like methods returning None (sources of buggs).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge`:

```
# dfP = PURCHASE dataframe
# dfS = SALES dataframe
out = (Purchases.merge(Sales.drop(columns='voucher'), on=['Name', 'item'],
                 suffixes=(None, '_'), how='left')
                .assign(Amt=lambda x: x['Amt'] - x.pop('Amt_').fillna(0).astype(int),
                        Qty=lambda x: x['Qty'] - x.pop('Qty_').fillna(0).astype(int),
                        voucher='Remaining'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Name   item    voucher   Amt  Qty
0    A  Item1  Remaining  4700   50
1    B  Item2  Remaining    50   10
2    B  Item1  Remaining   325    5
3    C  Item3  Remaining  -800    0
4    D  Item4  Remaining   500  100
5    A  Item3  Remaining  5000   50
```